# Subsetting data based on variable start date in R

Tags: r, date, subset

I am trying to write a bit of code that will grab a portion of a data frame based on start date, where each start date is different for each user.

Suppose I have the following data.frames (in reality my dataset is several orders of magnitude larger, but this will suffice as a sample set)

df1:

```
 >   df
      name   start.date
1  Allison   2013-03-16
2   Andrew   2013-03-16
3     Carl   2013-03-16
4     Dora   2013-03-17
5   Hilary   2013-03-17
6    Louis   2013-03-18
7     Mary   2013-03-19
8   Mickey   2013-03-20
```

And df2:

```
> df2
       names X03.16.2013 X03.17.2013 X03.18.2013  X03.19.2013
2001 Allison           5           5           0           0
2002  Andrew           2           0           0           0
2003    Carl           10          8           11          10
2004    Dora           0           4           0           0
2005  Hilary           0           3           5           0
2006   Louis           0           0           8           3
2007    Mary           0           0           0           7
2008  Mickey           0           0           0           0
```

I merged these two data frames into one called tmp:

```
>tmp

   name   start.date         X03.16.2013 X03.17.2013 X03.18.2013  X03.19.2013
    1  Allison   2013-03-16         5           5           0           0
    2   Andrew   2013-03-16         2           0           0           0
    3     Carl   2013-03-16         10          8           11          10
    4     Dora   2013-03-17         0           4           0           0
    5   Hilary   2013-03-17         0           3           5           0
    6    Louis   2013-03-18         0           0           8           3
    7     Mary   2013-03-19         0           0           0           7
    8   Mickey   2013-03-20         0           0           0           0
```

I also have a list of the column names of df2 converted to dates:

```
>dts

[1] "2014-03-16" "2014-03-17" "2014-03-18" "2014-03-19"
```

I thought one way to approach this problem is to change all the zero entries in df2 that occur before each user's start date to NA using the following nested loops:

```
for (i in 1:dim(tmp)[1]){
  for (j in 1:length(dts)){
    for (z in 4:dim(tmp)[2]){
    if (dts[j]< tmp$Date.of.Sign.Up[i]){
      tmp[i,z]<-NA
    } else {tmp[i,z]<-tmp[i,z]}
  }
}
}
```

The trouble with this loop is that 1. It will run infinitely and 2. Doesn't work. It is changing all the values in tmp from tmp[,3:end] to zero, regardless of start date. Ideally I would end up with something like this:

```
     name   start.date         X03.16.2013 X03.17.2013 X03.18.2013  X03.19.2013
  Allison   2013-03-16         5           5           0           0
   Andrew   2013-03-16         2           0           0           0
     Carl   2013-03-16         10          8           11          10
     Dora   2013-03-17         NA           4           0          0
   Hilary   2013-03-17         NA           3           5          0
    Louis   2013-03-18         NA           NA          8          3
     Mary   2013-03-19         NA           NA          NA         7
   Mickey   2013-03-20         NA           NA          NA         NA
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may reshape 'tmp' to long format, convert the former headers to dates, compare them with the start dates, and insert `NA` when start dates occur after the 'header dates':

```
library(reshape2)

# melt data from wide to long format
df3 <- melt(tmp, id.vars = c("name", "start.date"))

# convert 'variable' to class Date
df3$variable <- as.Date(df3$variable, format = "X%m.%d.%Y")

# compare start dates with 'variable dates' and insert NA
df3$value[df3$start.date > df3$variable] <- NA

# reshape back to wide
dcast(df3, name + start.date ~ variable)

#      name start.date 2013-03-16 2013-03-17 2013-03-18 2013-03-19
# 1 Allison 2013-03-16          5          5          0          0
# 2  Andrew 2013-03-16          2          0          0          0
# 3    Carl 2013-03-16         10          8         11         10
# 4    Dora 2013-03-17         NA          4          0          0
# 5  Hilary 2013-03-17         NA          3          5          0
# 6   Louis 2013-03-18         NA         NA          8          3
# 7    Mary 2013-03-19         NA         NA         NA          7
# 8  Mickey 2013-03-20         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

Another possibility where we loop over the 'date column names' in 'tmp':

```
dates <- names(tmp)[-c(1, 2)]

tmp[ , -c(1, 2)] <- sapply(dates, function(x){
  date <- as.Date(x, format = "X%m.%d.%Y")
  tmp[ , x][df2$start.date > date] <- NA
  tmp[ , x]
})

tmp  
#      name start.date X03.16.2013 X03.17.2013 X03.18.2013 X03.19.2013
# 1 Allison 2013-03-16           5           5           0           0
# 2  Andrew 2013-03-16           2           0           0           0
# 3    Carl 2013-03-16          10           8          11          10
# 4    Dora 2013-03-17          NA           4           0           0
# 5  Hilary 2013-03-17          NA           3           5           0
# 6   Louis 2013-03-18          NA          NA           8           3
# 7    Mary 2013-03-19          NA          NA          NA           7
# 8  Mickey 2013-03-20          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

Comment: when you wrote the statement `df3 <- melt(df2, id.vars = c("name", "start.date"))` did you mean to say `df3 <- melt(df, id.vars = c("name", "start.date"))`

Comment: For your second solution, I'm not getting any NAs put in. I wasn't sure if when you referred to df2 you meant to say tmp. I used the following code twice, once with the assumption you meant to say tmp everywhere you said df2 and once as is: `dates <- names(tmp)[-c(1, 2,3)]`
`tmp[ , -c(1,2,3)] <- sapply(dates, function(x){
    date <- as.Date(x, format = "X%m.%d.%Y")
   tmp[ , x][tmp$Date.of.Sign.Up < date] <- NA
    tmp[ , x]})`

Comment: both times no NAs were inserted

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the names of the data frames. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hmm, even with the edits to use tmp instead I am finding this is not a working solution as no values of NA are entered in replace of zero before the start date. I entered the following (note that for my larger dataset I needed to exclude the 3rd column of tmp as well, as it contains unrelated info) `tmp[ , -c(1,2,3)] <- sapply(dates, function(x){
    date <- as.Date(x, format = "X%m.%d.%Y")
   tmp[ , x][tmp$Date.of.Sign.Up > date] <- NA
    tmp[ , x]})`

Comment: Then it seems like your real dataset has peculiarities not present in the sample data. My answer works on _the data you provided_. You need to provide a minimal reproducible example of _sufficient complexity_, not more, not less. We are not mind readers.

Comment: Thank for you help and insight. I've marked your solution as accepted as I found it worked after ensuring my start.column was classified as a date. When I preformed the merge it lost this classification. Thank you.